# Google Datastudio: sum of several fields with the same name, how to target specific field

Tags: looker-studio

I have blended data with three fields, all named "Pageviews". When I create a new field which should be the sum of these three, I enter "Pageviews+Pageviews+Pageviews" which calculates the first field three times.

I know that internally, Google Studio stores these fields using a table alias such as table0.Pageviews.

If I knew what the table alias was, I could then write something like:

```
table0.Pageviews+table1.Pageviews
```

I cannot drag and drop the fields into the formula section, and doing a html code inspection does not yield a clue to what the table alias is.

How can I make sure I have the sum of three fields which all have the same name?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is possible to change the name of fields in the Blended data pane as per this image.

[image]